# Error authenticating a domain user for ssh connection

Tags: windows-10, ssh, openssh

I'm trying to setup my Windows 10 machine to be an ssh server by using [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH). The server is part of a domain, so I use the command

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa  -l user@domain ip_address
```

to connect from my ssh client.

This gives an error "Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)". On the server side, the log reads

> sshd: Invalid user user@domain from ip_address port 59676
>
> sshd: Connection closed by invalid user user@domain ip_address port 59676
> [preauth]

I have also tried the following variation on the ssh command

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa  domain/user@ip_address
```

to try to connect from the client side. I get a "Connection reset by ip_address port 22" error.

If I look at the log on the server side, it says:

> sshd: error: lookup_principal_name: User principal name lookup failed
> for user 'domain\user' (explicit: 5, implicit: 5)"
>
> sshd: error: get_user_token - unable to generate token on 2nd attempt for user
> domain\user
>
> sshd: fatal: ga_init, unable to resolve user domain\user

How can I resolve this error?

### Details

#### On the server (Windows 10) side:

`whoami` confirms that my username is domain\user

I'd like to use public key authentication only, so I set the permissions in sshd_config to

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
```

All other settings are default. The full sshd_config file follows

```
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
#SyslogFacility AUTH
#LogLevel INFO

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

#PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no

# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

I have the id_rsa.pub appended to the authorized_keys file in the C:\Users\user\.ssh directory. `icacls .\authorized_keys` returns

```
C:\Users\user\\.ssh\authorized_keys NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(F)
                  BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(F)
                  DOMAIN\user:(I)(F)
```

#### On the client (Ubuntu 20.04.3) side:

~/.ssh/id_rsa has the following permissions

```
-rw------- 1 ubuntu ubuntu 2655 Dec 30 18:16 id_rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  576 Dec 30 18:16 id_rsa.pub
```

Comment: The permissions on the key on the client must only be given to the owner of the key. Please submit your entire SSHD server configuration

Comment: The rest of the sshd_config is the default settings but I can include it if desired. Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but it looks to me like only the owner has read/write permissions for id_rsa.

Comment: Interested if you have the Administrator key commented or uncommented. So are you using the built-in version of OpenSSH? Outwork interest have you tried to authenticate has a local user on the machine. I was suggesting that the key on the server isn’t owned by just the user. Your configuration is apparently backwards to what I thought it was after reading your question again

Comment: I've added the config file. "AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys" is uncommented. I'm using [this version of OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/releases/tag/V8.6.0.0p1-Beta).

Comment: First, you need to disable the Administrator key.   You should also put the keys in the user directory, and make sure, the the ownership of the key is exclusive to the user you are attempting to use. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16212816/setting-up-openssh-for-windows-using-public-key-authentication/50502015#50502015) SO has a lot of good information.  Instead of using the version of OpenSSH you are using, I would use the optional Windows feature instead. Make sure the keys are located within `$env:USERPROFILE\.ssh`

Answer (score -1):

```
Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys
```

make these lines a comment line

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).